How to find a configuration of lines
In $\mathbb{R}^3$, can anyone help find a configuration of 5 lines such that the minimum of the smallest semi-axis lengths of the ellipsoid $ \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} = 1 $, where $\mathbf{A}$ is the Gram of the matrix consisting of the unit directional vectors of any 3 lines, is maximized over all configurations of 5 lines?
Thank you for any helpful answers!

Isn't "the minimum of the smallest angles between any three lines" just the minimum angle between any two lines?

@RavenclawPrefect  Thank you for your comment. It has been revised. Thanks!

So you are interested in unit directional vectors, not the lines themselves, don't you?

@MaxAlekseyev   Yeah, but it seems to be more convenient to describe in lines. Thanks.
